# Only Some Views Showing up in Google Analytics for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am having a strange issue with the Google Analytics SDK for iOS. I am able to track certain views just fine, but others don't appear at all. Im not sure what the problem is... Is this a common issue? All of my views are consistent and have the .h and .m references as listed below. Some of them have tableview delegates, etc. But I don't think that would be the problem. Is there another way I can implement this in the ones that don't seem to be working properly?

**.h Files:**

```
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : GAITrackedViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}
```

**.m Files:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.trackedViewName = @"Title to Track";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google analytics 3.02, you can do this:

Your .h file is fine;

In your .m file:

add this:

> `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
>     self.screenName = @"Title to Track";
>     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
>   }`

instead of adding trackingViewName in viewDidLoad method :)